# .after() Causing Tkinter Window To Freeze

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, freeze

I'm making a cookie clicker game in tkinter. I'm trying to program an auto click function for the player to buy that clicks the cookie every ten seconds. I attempted to use the `.after()` method, however this freezes the program. To clarify, the other functions such as the user clicking the cookie need to still be functional whilst the auto click runs in the background.

Here is the auto click function:

```
def autoclick():
        def tensecs():
            while True:
                global clicks
                clicks = clicks + 1
                if clicks == 1:
                    lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookie!".format(clicks))
                else:
                    lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookies!".format(clicks))
        shop_window.after(1000, tensecs)
```

Here is the full program:

```
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Canvas
import ttk
import time
window1 = Tk()
window1.title("Cookie Clicker")
window1.config(background="dodger blue")
window1.geometry("254x390")
clicks = 0


class FlashableLabel(Label):
    def flash(self, count):
        bg = self.cget('background')
        fg = self.cget('foreground')
        self.configure(background=fg, foreground=bg)
        count += 1
        if count < 1000:
            self.after(250, self.flash, count)


def cookie_clicks(event):
    global clicks
    clicks = clicks + 1
    pb.step(10)
    print("{0}".format(clicks))
    if clicks == 1:
        lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookie!".format(clicks))
    else:
        lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookies!".format(clicks))


def about_btn():
    about_window = Toplevel(window1)
    about_window.overrideredirect(1)
    about_window.geometry("230x150+15+50")
    about_window.config(background="snow2")
    photo4 = PhotoImage(file="imageedit_4_8477195169.gif")
    photolbl = Label(about_window, image=photo4, borderwidth=0)
    photolbl.image = photo4
    photolbl.pack()
    lbl3 = Label(about_window, text="Cookie Clicker", bg="snow2", fg="black", font=("Lucida Grande bold", 14))
    lbl3.pack()
    lbl4 = Label(about_window, text="Version 13.0.4 (24502.5.6)", bg="snow2", fg="black", font=("Lucida Grande", 9))
    lbl4.pack()
    copyright_symb = u'\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN}'.encode('utf-8')
    lbl5 = Label(about_window, text="Copyright {0} 2003-2018 Hatna Inc.\nAll rights reserved.".format(copyright_symb), bg="snow2", fg="black", font=("Lucida Grande", 10))
    lbl5.pack()


def shop_btn():

    def autoclick():
        def tensecs():
            while True:
                global clicks
                clicks = clicks + 1
                if clicks == 1:
                    lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookie!".format(clicks))
                else:
                    lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookies!".format(clicks))
        shop_window.after(1000, tensecs)

    def double():
        global clicks
        if clicks >= 20:
            clicks = clicks * 2
            clicks = clicks - 20
            if clicks == 1:
                lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookie!".format(clicks))
            else:
                lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookies!".format(clicks))
            shop_window.destroy()
            global lbl3
            lbl3.configure(text="", fg="dodger blue")
        else:
            shop_window.destroy()
            lbl3.configure(text="You Need More Cookies!", fg="snow2")

    shop_window = Toplevel(window1)
    shop_window.overrideredirect(1)
    shop_window.geometry("254x310+5+50")
    frame = Frame(shop_window, width=254, height=310)
    frame.pack()
    canvas = Canvas(frame, width=254, height=310, bg="dodger blue", bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge", scrollregion=(0, 0, 500, 500))
    vbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
    vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 254, 40, outline="snow2", fill="snow2")
    lbl3 = canvas.create_text(135, 20, text="{0} Cookies".format(clicks), fill="dodger blue", font=("kavoon", 15))
    global photo5
    photo5 = PhotoImage(file="imageedit_1_6195264074.gif")
    photolbl = canvas.create_image(20, 20, image=photo5)
    x2 = canvas.create_text(35, 120, text="X2", fill="gray", font=("arial bold", 40))
    lbl4 = canvas.create_text(115, 110, text="Double Your Score", fill="black", font=("arial bold", 12))
    lbl5 = canvas.create_text(94, 129, text="20 Cookies", fill="black", font=("arial", 12))
    buybtn1 = Button(canvas, text="Buy", highlightbackground="dodger blue", command=double)
    buybtn1_window = canvas.create_window(210, 119.5, window=buybtn1)
    global photo6
    photo6 = PhotoImage(file="imageedit_24_7373388957.gif")
    photolbl2 = canvas.create_image(32.5, 70, image=photo6)
    lbl6 = canvas.create_text(124, 61, text="10 Second Auto-Click", fill="black", font=("arial bold", 12))
    lbl5 = canvas.create_text(94, 80, text="15 Cookies", fill="black", font=("arial", 12))
    buybtn2 = Button(canvas, text="Buy", highlightbackground="dodger blue", command=autoclick)
    buybtn2_window = canvas.create_window(210, 70, window=buybtn2)


w = Canvas(window1, width=254, height=80, highlightbackground="snow2")
w.pack()
w.create_rectangle(10, 10, 80, 80, outline="snow2", fill="snow2", width=100000)
cookie = Button(window1, highlightbackground="dodger blue", borderwidth=0, cursor="hand2")
cookie.bind('<Button-1>', cookie_clicks)
window1.bind('<Return>', cookie_clicks)
photo = PhotoImage(file="imageedit_3_3213999137.gif")
cookie.config(image=photo, width="250", height="250")
cookie.place(x=0, y=90)
w2 = Canvas(window1, width=0.1, height=250, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w2.place(x=0, y=86)
w3 = Canvas(window1, width=0.1, height=250, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w3.place(x=249, y=86)
w4 = Canvas(window1, width=250, height=0.1, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w4.place(x=0, y=88)
w5 = Canvas(window1, width=250, height=0.1, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w5.place(x=0, y=338)
lbl1 = Label(window1, bg="snow2", fg="dodger blue", text="{0} Cookies!".format(clicks), font=("kavoon", 20))
lbl1.place(x=75, y=40)
lbl2 = Label(window1, bg="snow2", fg="dodger blue", text="Cookie Clicker", font=("kavoon", 30))
lbl2.place(x=20, y=0)
pb = ttk.Progressbar(window1, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate')
pb.place(x=76, y=68)
shop = Button(window1, highlightbackground="dodger blue", borderwidth=0, command=shop_btn)
photo2 = PhotoImage(file="imageedit_28_9392607524.gif")
shop.config(image=photo2, width="44", height="40")
shop.place(x=5, y=345)
w6 = Canvas(window1, width=38, height=0.1, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w6.place(x=7, y=345)
w7 = Canvas(window1, width=38, height=0.1, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w7.place(x=7, y=381)
w8 = Canvas(window1, width=0.1, height=25, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w8.place(x=6, y=350)
w9 = Canvas(window1, width=0.1, height=25, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w9.place(x=45, y=350)
info = Button(window1, highlightbackground="dodger blue", borderwidth=0, command=about_btn)
photo3 = PhotoImage(file="imageedit_48_3021448243.gif")
info.config(image=photo3, width="44", height="40")
info.place(x=49, y=345)
w10 = Canvas(window1, width=38, height=0.1, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w10.place(x=51, y=345)
w11 = Canvas(window1, width=38, height=0.1, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w11.place(x=51, y=381)
w12 = Canvas(window1, width=0.1, height=25, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w12.place(x=50, y=350)
w13 = Canvas(window1, width=0.1, height=25, highlightbackground="dodger blue")
w13.place(x=90, y=350)
lbl3 = FlashableLabel(window1, bg="dodger blue", fg="dodger blue", text="", font=("kavoon", 12))
lbl3.place(x=100, y=353)
lbl3.flash(0)

window1.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated! and please excuse my GUI's bad formatting, I've not quite began to experiment with `.grid`.

Comment: The simple answer is to not use `.after()`

Comment: Use an actual loop

Comment: The issue is not the actual use of `.after()` but likely the function it is calling. The `while True` statement looks like it might be the problem.

Comment: @Hippolippo I need to use .after() because it delays the amount of cookies from increasing by ten seconds.

Comment: you don't need `.after` just use something like `if time.now() - startTime >= 1/cps: ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `after()` *instead of* a while loop, not in addition to. Try this:

```
def autoclick():
    global clicks
    clicks = clicks + 1
    if clicks == 1:
        lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookie!".format(clicks))
    else:
        lbl1.configure(text="{0} Cookies!".format(clicks))
    shop_window.after(1000, autoclick) # repeat this function every second
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I was just over complicating the function.

Comment: you would get delay from the execution time of the code so it would be inaccurate because it would be more than a second.